# What is the best way to deal with a Python project folder which has multiple Python scripts which have different requirements than each other?

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv

Say I am using an IDE like PyCharm and I have created a project folder called `my_project` which has a virtual environment folder inside for that project, say `venv` along with multiple Python scripts (`script_1, script_2...`) which I am working on.

However at some point I realise that some of my python scripts within `my_project` folder (say `script_1`) requires a different python version/ package dependencies etc than the other python files (say `script_2`).

#### So my question is:

Is it then possible to create a new virtual environment folder, say `venv2` and place it within the `my_projects` folder as well and then activate and run that environment on the python script which requires it? If so when switching back and forth between the scripts would you have to `activate & deactivate` the different environments? Is this easily done on IDE such as PyCharm or would you suggest using terminal commands?

Comment: Those are arguably different *projects* then…?!

Comment: Would `script_1 & script_2` have to be considered differently and put into separate projects if each script requires different virtual environments then? 

What I meant was say `script_1` is an script for ML model building and say `script_2` is also a code for ML model building but the model for this script requires different packages and python versions. I can't use 1 virtual environment as `script_2` wouldn't work as the python version/ packages required are different. 

What would your suggestions be for this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's quite easily done in PyCharm. You can have as many virtual environments as you want. I recommend adding them via `Add Python Interpreter` dialog in the IDE.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html#python_create_virtual_env

Then you can create a run configuration for each script (`Run > Edit Configurations...`) where you can choose which interpreter will run it.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html

Comment: Cool thanks, so when you create a new configuration and run from your script using that configuration this solves the problem of having to create a new project for each script as you can now just use the configuration you want for a particular script?

Comment: Yes, in the configuration settings, use the `Python interpreter` setting to select the appropriate virtual environment interpreter for your script (choose one that is not marked as Project Default). Run configurations can then be quickly accessed and rerun with the `Ctrl-F10` shortcut.